# Making sure public VBA methods don't show up in the list of Excel macros

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA (2003), I've noticed that any **Public** or **Friend**  **Sub** method in either a module or *ThisWorkbook* that doesn't have any arguments will show up as a Macro that can be run by the user. I.e. when the user goes to Tools --> Macro --> Macros... (or Alt+F8) the method will show up in the list that can be run.

For sanity's sake (organization, maintenance, etc) I do need to separate the code into modules. I'm hoping to find a non-hacky way to hide some methods from the user, but still allow them to be visible to other code modules. Note that all the code is contained within the same *application*, so no external code is called.

My current work-around is to use **Function**s that return a boolean instead of **Sub**s, and just ignore the return value. eJames suggested the option of using an optional argument in the **Sub**, which will also hide the method from the list of macros.

Neither of these feel quite right, however, so any advice about how to structure a non-trivial Excel VBA application would be much appreciated.

Comment: wow great, using @Jason Z answer could also decreases size of my excel file (117 kb.) (excel 2003)

Comment: That's surprising. I believe it may have happened due to saving workbook in compile vs non-compile mode. Using Option Private Module effectively has no direct effect on file size.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Add the following to the top of your module:

```
Option Private Module
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266185(VS.60).aspx):

> When a module contains Option Private
>   Module, the public parts, for example,
>   variables, objects, and user-defined
>   types declared at module level, are
>   still available within the project
>   containing the module, but they are
>   not available to other applications or
>   projects.

Comment: I had shield away from this at first because it can't be used in 'object' modules like ThisWorkbook or sheets... but that problem was me having methods where I shouldn't. Thanks for this.

Comment: wow great, using this method can also decreases size of your excel file (for me: 117 kb.) (excel 2003)

Comment: Perhaps we should all have `Option Private Module` at the tops of our code modules as a rule – except where the module contains procedures called by buttons.

Answer (score 8):

One solution is to give the method an `Optional` argument.

```
Public Sub myPublicSub(Optional dummy_var As Integer)
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, eJames. I had meant to mention that as an option in my question too. In my mind, that 'smells' even worse than turning the public Sub ino a function. :)

Answer (score 8):

Just a small addendum to Jason Z's answer: methods hidden by `Option Private Module` are still visible if you use `Application.Run()` to invoke the method.

Answer (score 3):

Also worth noting a side effect of both **Option Private Module** and adding Optional Params is that the Sub will no longer work as a target of a shortcut keybinding.

Restated: If you have a keybinding to set a keyboard shortcut to launch a Macro.  That Macro cannot be hidden.  Otherwise the keybinding will not work.

Comment: Not quite true.  If you use e.James' method above of a dummy argument you can still hide the sub from the "macros" dialog and have a keybinding.  You can either bind the key then add the dummy argument, or do the keybinding/unbinding during Workbook_Open/BeforeClose or App_WorkbookActivate events.

Answer (score 1):

My methods have already been listed however, ChrisB made the following statement:

> Perhaps we should all have Option Private Module at the tops of our
> code modules as a rule – except where the module contains procedures
> called by buttons

Even Private routines can be called from a button if the Macro is assigned to the button before making it private.