# Check Return value of private sub

Tags: excel, vba, return-value

In an Excel 2007 workbook I have three Excel modules, each containing one subroutine.  The Driver sub (UpdateDataFromOracle) calls the subs UpdateResponse and UpdateSched.  The code is working fine, but I'd like to  check the "return code" of each of the called subs.  I only want the Driver sub visible to the user, so I made the subs in Modules 1 and 2 Private.
Module 1  Private Sub  UpdateResponse
Module 2  Private Sub  UpdateSched
Module 3  Public Sub   UpdateDataFromOracle

Here's code from the Driver sub

```
Sub UpdateDataFromOracle()
'DECLARE VARIABLES
Dim varSchedReturn as variant
'...
Call UpdateResponse
Call UpdateSched
'I Would like to insert the "return code" check here
End Sub
```

Here's code from the Called sub

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UpdateResponse()
'DECLARE VARIABLES
'...
If Sheets(strTempSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count > 10 Then
  UpdateResponse = 0
Else UpdateResponse = 90
End If
End Sub
```

To call the Private subs I had to abandon the "Call" and use"

```
Application.Run "Module1.UpdateResponse"
```

But I can't figure out how to get a return code that way.
I also made UpdateResponse and UpdateSched Private Functions, but I still couldn't figure out how to get a return code back.
When I made UpdateResponse and UpdateSched Public Functions, I can use a statement at the end of the called subs like:

```
Else UpdateResponse = 90
```

The problem is that the called subroutines are visible to the user if I leave the functions Public.

My goal is to have only the Driver sub visible to the user, and be able to evaluate some sort of "Return Code" from the called subs in the Driver sub.
Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: Use `Option Private Module` below `Option Explicit` in the modules that have the functions you don't want the users to see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/296696/293078

Comment: As a side note: if you need return variables with the same name as the Sub then use Function instead of Sub

Comment: Hello Doug.  The Option Private Module below Option Explicit did the trick.  I turned the called subroutines into functions.  Then, all I had to do in the driver program was use the statements: varModule1Return = UpdateResponse and another statement varModule2Return = UpdateSched  As I'm sure you're aware, placing the function name on the right side of the equals sign causes the function to be executed.  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. One other tip, this one just about SO. If you put an "@" in front of somebody's name, e.g., @DougGlancy, they'll be notified about your comment. Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully read the question, but change them to Function

```
Private Function UpdateResponse() As Integer
    'DECLARE VARIABLES
    '...
    If Sheets(strTempSheet).UsedRange.Rows.Count > 10 Then
        UpdateResponse = 0
    Else 
        UpdateResponse = 90
    End If
End Function
```

Then:

```
Dim response         ' As Variant or Integer 
response = Application.Run("Module1.UpdateResponse")
```

Also, there are 2 better ways with `Option Private Module` or a public variable in Module1

[3 Ways to Call a Private Sub from Another Module](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/3-ways-to-call-a-private-sub-from-another-module/)

Comment: Hello Slai,  That didn't seem to work for me.  Using the "Option Private Module" in the called functions seemed to do the trick.  That suggestion came from Doug Glancy above.

Answer (score 0):

The answer @DougGlancy gave worked well.  It's listed as a comment to my original question, so I'm adding this Answer to indicate that his answer was correct.

Answer (score -1):

One option for Windows Excel that I have used is to set values on the user's machine that can be retrieved in a later process.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Alternatives could be to set some properties of your Excel workbook or in Excel you can create names and values associated with them. (part of named ranges).

Lastly, you can add and change values in the windows registry.

Comment: These are way too complicated.